# How to find the maximum possible number of items could be placed in a UICollectionView row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How to find the maximum possible number of items could be placed in a `UICollectionView`row?

In the following example which is 3.

[image]

Comment: You should create a formula, something like total width/(collection view cell width + padding) = number of items in a row

Comment: Are you using a custom layout or a flow layout ?

Comment: That might depend on screen size, orientation, cell width, padding etc. `UICollectionView` is meant to be dynamic so I wouldn't expect things to be constant.

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes it's a custom layout for reordering. But more or less a standard flow layout.

Comment: @Adam The layout lays the cells finally by calculating the circumstances, therefore it knows that information (how many rows and columns) too. How to get that out?

Comment: There is no public API for that. I guess Apple doesn't want it to be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's UICollectionViewFlowLayout doesn't "know" the max number of items it can display on the screen. It basically just calculates the coordinates of the next cell to place it next to the previous one and verifies if it fits in the screen on the fly. If it doesn't, it will recalculate new coordinates to place the cell as first element of the next line/column (depending on the orientation).

You could do the same with a formula. Something like this maybe :

```
int verticalCount = (int)((self.collectionViewContentSize.width - self.minimumInteritemSpacing)/(self.itemSize.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing));
int horizontalCount = (int)((self.collectionViewContentSize.height - self.minimumLineSpacing)/(self.itemSize.height + self.minimumLineSpacing));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this fomula

```
int noOfCell = (self.view.frame.size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding)/(cell.frame.size.width + spacebetweenCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

After considering the answer form **@Kujey** and with a slide change I could find the solution as follows.

```
func maximumNumberOfCellsInARow() -> Int {

    let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    return Int((collectionView.contentSize.width - collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)/(collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize.width + collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing))
}
```

@Kujey, sorry I could not mark your answer as a right answer even though my answer is driven from yours, because it needs a significant change.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this formula, you can complicate it including section insets and other params.

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSUInteger totalItems = X; 
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    NSLog(@"MAX WIDTH: %li",(long) collectionView.frame.size.width);

    NSUInteger maxVisibleItems = (collectionView.frame.size.width + collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing) / (collectionViewLayout.itemSize.width + collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing);

    NSLog(@"MAX VISIBLE ITEMS: %li",(long) maxVisibleItems);
    if (totalItems < maxVisibleItems ) {
       return totalItems;
    }else{

       return maxVisibleItems;
    }

}
```